# CSS not working correctly in form

Tags: css

Hi I was trying to make an order form, and everything was working fine until I got towards the end of making the style sheet for the website. Then the whole thing messed up and the legends of the form are going all the way to the right end of the page and the drop down boxes are displaying all options from left to right instead of top to bottom. Could anyone look this CSS sheet over and tell me where i screwed up?

Thanks from a novice website person.

```
/*fieldset styles */

fieldset {
border-width: 0px;
}

fieldset.optiongroup {
margin-left: 25%;
}

fieldset.optiongroup label {
float: none;
display: inline;
width: 100px;
}

/* legend styles */

legend {
background-color: rgb(239, 198, 145);
color: black;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
text-indent: 20px;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 10px;
}

/* label styles */

label {
clear: left;
display: block;
float: left;
font-size: 0.8em;
text-align: right;
margin: 2px 5px;
width: 25%;
}


/* select styles */

select {
display: block;
float: left;
font-size: 0.9em;
margin: 2px;
}

/* text area styles */

textarea {
display: block;
float: left;
font-size: 0.9em;
height: 75px;
width: 60%;
}

/* option styles */

option {
float: none;
display: inline;
margin: 0px;
width: 20px;
}

/* input styles */

input {
display: block;
float: left;
font-size: 0.9em;
width: 60%;
margin: 2px 0px;
}

input[type="csc"] {
width: 50px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
background-color: rgb(239, 198, 145);
float: none;
width: 150px;
height: 30px;
margin: 10px auto;
border-radius: 15px;
}

/* input focus styles */

input:focus, select:focus, textarea:focus {
background-color: rgb(255, 218, 165);
}

input:focus:valid {
background: rgb(215, 255, 215) url(go.png) bottom right no-repeat;

-o-background-size: contain;
-moz-background-size: contain;
-webkit-background-size: contain;
background-size: contain;
}

input:focus:invalid {
background: rgb(255, 245, 215) url(stop.png) bottom right no-repeat;

-o-background-size: contain;
-moz-background-size: contain;
-webkit-background-size: contain;
background-size: contain;
```

If need b I can post the HTML site here as well. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
   <!--
      New Perspectives on HTML and CSS
      Tutorial 6
      Case Problem 2

      The Spice Bowl
      Author: Daniel Erb
      Date:   21SEP13

      Filename:         spice.htm
      Supporting files: diners.png, discover.png, formsubmit.js,
                        go.png, master.png, modernizr-1.5.js, payment.css, 
                        regex.txt, sb.css, sbback.png, sblogo.png,
                        state.txt, stop.png, visa.png
-->
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>Spice Bowl Financial Information</title>
      <script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
      <script src="formsubmit.js"></script>
      <link href="sb.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="payment.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

   </head>


   <body>
      <header>
         <img src="sblogo.png" alt="The Spice Bowl" />
      </header>

      <nav>
         <ul>
            <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Keyword Search</a></li>

            <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Spices</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Seasonings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blends</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Salts &amp; Peppers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Popcorn Seasonings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dip Mixes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bulk Spices</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Extracts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Flavorings</a></li>

            <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Spice Jars</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Spice Jar Labels</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Spice Sets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mortar &amp; Pestles</a></li>

            <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Cookbooks</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Online Recipes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>

            <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Checkout</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Order History</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shipping Info</a></li>

            <li class="newgroup"><a href="#">Tech Support</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hours</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>

      <section>

         <h1>Payment Form</h1>
         <form id="Payment Form" name="Payment Form"
                action="http://www.thespicebowlcorp.com/cgi-bin/payment"
                method="post">
        <fieldset id="Billing">
            <legend>Billing Information (required)</legend>

            <label for="fName">First Name</label>
            <input name="fName" id="fName" required="required" />

            <label for="lName">Last Name</label>
            <input name="lName" id="lName" required="required" />

            <label for="street">Street Address</label>
            <input name="street" id="street" required="required" />

            <label for="street2">Street Address (2)</label>
            <input name="street2" id="street2" />

            <label for="city">City</label>
            <input name="city" id="city" required="required" />

            <label for="State">State</label>
            <select name="State" id="State" required="required">
                <option value="state1">AL</option>
                <option value="state2">AK</option>
                <option value="state3">AZ</option>
                <option value="state4">AR</option>
                <option value="state5">CA</option>
                <option value="state6">CO</option>
                <option value="state7">CT</option>
                <option value="state8">DE</option>
                <option value="state9">FL</option>
                <option value="state10">GA</option>
                <option value="state11">HI</option>
                <option value="state12">ID</option>
                <option value="state13">IL</option>
                <option value="state14">IN</option>
                <option value="state15">IA</option>
                <option value="state16">KS</option>
                <option value="state17">KY</option>
                <option value="state18">LA</option>
                <option value="state19">ME</option>
                <option value="state20">MD</option>
                <option value="state21">MA</option>
                <option value="state22">MI</option>
                <option value="state23">MN</option>
                <option value="state24">MS</option>
                <option value="state25">MO</option>
                <option value="state26">MT</option>
                <option value="state27">NE</option>
                <option value="state28">NV</option>
                <option value="state29">NH</option>
                <option value="state30">NJ</option>
                <option value="state31">NM</option>
                <option value="state32">NY</option>
                <option value="state33">NC</option>
                <option value="state34">ND</option>
                <option value="state35">OH</option>
                <option value="state36">OK</option>
                <option value="state37">OR</option>
                <option value="state38">PA</option>
                <option value="state39">RI</option>
                <option value="state40">SC</option>
                <option value="state41">SD</option>
                <option value="state42">TN</option>
                <option value="state43">TX</option>
                <option value="state44">UT</option>
                <option value="state45">VT</option>
                <option value="state46">VA</option>
                <option value="state47">WA</option>
                <option value="state48">WV</option>
                <option value="state49">WI</option>
                <option value="state50">WY</option>
            </select>

            <label for="zip">Zip/Postal Code</label>
            <input name="zip" id="zip"
                    placeholder="nnnnn (-nnnn)"
                    required="required"
                    pattern="^\d{5}(\-\d{4})?$" />

            <label for="country">Country</label>
            <input name="country" id="country" required="required" value="United States" />

            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <input name="phone" id="phone" type="tel"
                    placeholder="(nnn) nnn-nnnn"
                    required="required"
                    pattern="^\d{10}$|^(\(\d{3}\)\s*)?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="Credit Card">
            <legend>Credit Card (required)</legend>
            <fieldset id="optionGroup">
                <label for="Diners"><img src="diners.png" alt="Diner" /></label>
                <input type="radio" name="ccard" id="Diner"
                        value="Diner" />
                <label for="Discover"><img src="discover.png" alt="Discover" /></label>
                <input type="radio" name="ccard" id="Discover"
                        value="Discover" />
                <label for="Master"><img src="master.png" alt="Master" /></label>
                <input type="radio" name="ccard" id="Master"
                        value="Master" />
                <label for="Visa"><img src="visa.png" alt="Visa" /></label>
                <input type="radio" name="ccard" id="Visa"
                        value="Visa" />
            </fieldset>

            <label for="Credit Card Number">Credit Card Number</label>
            <input name="Credit Card Number" id="Credit Card Number"
                    required="required"
                    pattern="^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$" />

            <label for="Expiration">Expiration Date</label>
            <select name="ccardmonth" id="ccardmonth" required="required">
                <option value="month0">--Month--</option>
                <option value="month1">January (01)</option>
                <option value="month2">February (02)</option>
                <option value="month3">March (03)</option>
                <option value="month4">April (04)</option>
                <option value="month5">May (05)</option>
                <option value="month6">June (06)</option>
                <option value="month7">July (07)</option>
                <option value="month8">August (08)</option>
                <option value="month9">September (09)</option>
                <option value="month10">October (10)</option>
                <option value="month11">November (11)</option>
                <option value="month12">December (12)</option>
            </select>
            <select name="ccardyear" id="ccardyear" required="required">
                <option value="year0">--Year--</option>
                <option value="year1">2014</option>
                <option value="year2">2015</option>
                <option value="year3">2016</option>
                <option value="year4">2017</option>
                <option value="year5">2018</option>
            </select>

            <label for="CSC">CSC</label>
            <input name="CSC" id="CSC"
                placeholder="nnn"
                required="required"
                pattern="^\d{3}$" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="Additional Information">
            <legend>Additional Information</legend>

            <label for="email">Contact Email</label>
            <input name="email" id="email" type="email" />

            <label for="notes">Special Notes</label>
            <textarea name="notes" id="notes"></textarea>
        </fieldset>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Order" />
        </p>

        </form>
         <footer>
            <address>The Spice Bowl &#183; 871 Park St. &#183; 
                     East Point, GA 30344
                     &#183; (404) 555- 8711
            </address>
         </footer>

      </section>


      <aside>
         <h1>The Spice Bowl Recommends</h1>
         <h2>Salt-Roasted Pecans</h2>
         <ul>
            <li>2 cups pecans</li>
            <li>3 Tbs. butter, melted</li>
            <li>1 1/4 tsp. fine sea salt</li>
         </ul>
         <p>Preheat oven to 325&deg;. Toss pecans and butter together; 
            add salt and toss again.  Spread in a single layer on a baking 
            sheet.  Bake about 15 minutes.  Cook on baking sheet.
         </p>

         <h2>Dried Beef Sticks</h2>
         <ul>
            <li>5 lbs. ground chuck</li>
            <li>5 Tbs. quick salt</li>
            <li>3 tsp. mustard seed</li>
            <li>2 tsp. granulated garlic</li>
            <li>2 tsp. cracked pepper</li>
            <li>1 Tbs. hickory smoked salt</li>
            <li>1 Tbs. liquid smoke</li>
         </ul>
         <p>Mix beef and season.  Place in a large covered container 
            for three days; make sure beef is thoroughly mixed each day.  
            On third day, shape beef into sticks, and bake at 150&deg; for 
            8 hours (turn half-way through).
         </p>
      </aside>


   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please, we can't help you if you don't show us your html.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the markup(html)? You are using % as units for width on some elements like legend. I am not seeing a parent container element with a fixed width set, so the legend is going to being 100% of your page.